# unable to access the service via virtual service in Istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm new to **istio** and I have my the entire code in http://github.com/VenkateshSrini/IstioTest. I have created the service needed for hosting the Kubernetes service (`istio-test-deployment.yaml` in the repo). I tested it on **docker desktop for windows** (Kubernetes enabled) and I got the same working correctly. I had exposed my service via port `5000`. In docker for windows the external Ip is always localhost.

Now using istoctl I created a created a side car deployment. That can be seen from `istio-test-dep-injected.yaml`. I executed this and service was created with Sidecar. Now the same service is not accessible via `http://localHost:5000`, which I think is correct

Then I went ahead and created the Virtual Gateway. The definition of the same can be seen at virtual-gateway.yaml. Then I created a virtual service as per virtualservice.yaml. In that I have provided the host and the name of Kubernetes service name and the port as 5000.

Even after all this I'm unable to access the Service using the url `http://localHost/api/version`

Can someone help me, because I do not find much help working with Istio with Docker for Windows

Comment: Maybe it is related with `match` rule in `VirtualService`? https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#HTTPRoute
Can you just map root endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot adding match rule. Try following add `match` field

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: istio-test-virtualservice
spec:
  gateways:
  - istio-test-gateway
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-test
        port:
          number: 5000
```

Comment: Still not working. I tried accessing the service with localhost:31380/api/version and then tried localhost:5000/api/version and then tried localhost/api/version  but stillnot working. I tried even giving the host as istio-test.istio-apps.svc.local and even localhost that also did not work. Badly stuck

Comment: Additionally I see this in pod logs Error from server (BadRequest): a container name must be specified for pod istio-test-5744c6c67d-f676h, choose one of: [istio-test istio-proxy] or one of the init containers: [istio-init]

Comment: I have raised the issue with the Istio team also @https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/10568 but there also I'm not getting any response